# Random copies of an object?

Tags: unity

If I press C<\kbd>, several copies of a prefab show up in the scene. However, my script only creates one. I need to make a random copies, like between 1 to 5.

How do I do this?

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C)) 
{
    Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a couple of problems, here. I am going to try and tackle them, in order, to best explain your situation and solution.

### Input with `Input.GetKey`

First and foremost, for the type of reaction you want your input to have, you are most certainly using the wrong `GetKey` method. Let's take a look at `GetKey`, in [the Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html):

> #### [Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html).GetKey
>
> public static bool **GetKey**([KeyCode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html)**key**);
> **Description**
> Returns true while the user holds down the `key` [KeyCode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) enum parameter. ***Think auto fire***.
> <sub>[- Input.GetKey @ docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)</sub>

Your checking if the key *is* pressed; however, your game updates 50-60 times, per second. If you check if the key *is* pressed, you are going to have multiple method calls; nobody can explicitly press a key for 1/60th of a second. You *want* to be checking if the key *was* pressed. This way, we only call the method *once*.

> #### [Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html).GetKeyDown
>
> public static bool **GetKeyDown**([KeyCode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html)**key**);
> **Description**
> Returns true during the frame the user **starts** pressing down the `key` [KeyCode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) enum parameter.
> **You need to call this function from the Update function**, since the state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again.
> <sub>[- Input.GetKeyDown @ docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)</sub>

#### Making Multiple Copies

Next, we need to actually make the multiple copies. In your case, you have a line that makes a single copy. Forget the multiple copies that spawn, as with correct input implementation, this will give you a single object:

```
Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
```

How do we make multiple objects? We call the line to make *one* object, *multiple* times.

```
Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
```

This works, but it looks messy. We only had to copy and paste the line, so it was not much work, but we could make this look much better with a loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
}
```

This will loop through the line, five times. In turn, this will create 5 copies of your game object.

#### Using `Random`

Using random can be complicated. Luckily, it is done for you. The `UnityEngine` namespace has a method that takes in a minimum and maximum number, and spits out a random number, between them.

Note that `System` also has a method defined as `Random`. If you are using the `System` namespace, you will also have to define `Random = UnityEngine.Random`, so you ensure you call the correct method.

Also note that there are *two* variations of `UnityEngine.Random`. They are defined by the *types* you use. *Do not get them mixed up*, or you may have unexpected behaviour.

- `Random(int min, int max)` handles the values as *integer* numbers. As such, this method will randomly return a number from `min` to `max`, but will *not* return `max`.
- `Random(float min, float max)` handles the values as *floating point* numbers. As such, this method will randomly return a number from `min` to `max`, but unlike the `int` variation, *may* return `max`.

---

There you have it. When you put all of these concepts into practice, instantiating a random amount of game objects on key press is really quite simple.

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        InstantiateRandom(5);
    }
}

void InstantiateRandom(int max)
{
    // Increase max by 1, to include original value in random.
    // Remember, integer random will not return the max value.
    max++;

   // Convert max to a random integer within its range.
    max = Random(1, max);

    // Use the random integer to loop through our Instantiate line.
    for(int i = 0; i <= max; I++)
    {
        Instantiate(Diamonds,transform.position,transform.rotation);
    }
}
```